# SQL query for 2 tables without the key I want to search in for 2

Tags: sql

I have the following problem. I have 2 tables Courses and Declarations.

Courses table :

| courseid [PK] | userid | semesterid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

Declarations table :

| declarationid [PK] | courseid | semesterid | studentname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Nick |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | John |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | LAura |

Now I need to combine the 2 tables, so I can see declarations only from a specific user. The only common things between the 2 tables are the courseid. I am not sure how to get the result I want.

e.g. I would like all declarations with userid 1.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate atabase tags.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want something like this :

```
select d.* 
from Declarations as d, Courses as c
where d.courseid = c.courseid
   and c.userid = 'YourDisiredId'
```

where `YourDisiredId` is the id of the specific user you want to see Declarations data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need an inner join and where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM d Declarations
INNER JOIN c Courses on c.courseid = d.courseid
WHERE c.user_id = 1;
```